# Adobe AIR Native Extension TWAIN Image Scanner

Tags: c++, image-processing, air, air-native-extension, twain

Currently I am working on Adobe AIR Native extension which gives possibilities to simple manipulate image scanner using TWAIN. 
I use **CTwain** class found at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/296/A-C-Wrapper-for-TWAIN 
 
When i use this class in Windows Application (.exe) it works as expected, but in dll (which i need to create ane file) it **crashes when Twain Device UI is closing (when scan complete or by clicking Cancel button)**
 I thing the problem is somewhere in DllMain.cpp file (possibly message loop), because in application with starting function **APIENTRY _tWinMain** it works perfect.

Code

DllMain.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TwainCpp.h"
#include "resource.h"

using namespace std;

HWND g_hwnd = NULL;
HINSTANCE g_hInstance = NULL;
BOOL isValid = false;
BOOL isCreated = false;
CTwain *twain = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, unsigned message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:         
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:            
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }   
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL CreateAppWindow()
{
    WNDCLASS  wc;
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = g_hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_APPWORKSPACE + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName =  "FRETwainMenu";
    wc.lpszClassName = "FRETwainClass";

    if(RegisterClass(&wc))
    {
        HWND hWnd;          
            char title[50];
            wsprintf(title, "FRETwain:%x", g_hInstance);
            hWnd = CreateWindow("FRETwainClass", title, WS_DISABLED,               CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,                      HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, g_hInstance, NULL);
            if(hWnd)
            {       
                g_hwnd = hWnd;                  
                return TRUE;                    
            }               
            return FALSE;       
    }   
    return FALSE;
}

DWORD WINAPI CreateAppThread()
{   
    if(CreateAppWindow())
    {
        MSG msg;
        isCreated = true;
        while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
        {
            if(twain != NULL){              
                twain->ProcessMessage(msg);             
            }   
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);                      
        }       
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD reason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch(reason)
    {
         case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            g_hInstance = hInstance;            
            HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)CreateAppThread, (LPVOID)NULL, 0, NULL);
            break;
    }        
    return TRUE;
}
```

FRETwain.cpp (context file)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "FRETwain.h"

extern BOOL isValid;
extern BOOL isCreated;
extern HWND g_hwnd;
extern CTwain *twain;

extern "C"
{   
    FREObject AcquireTwain(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
    {   
        FREObject result;
        uint32_t ret = 0;   
        if(isValid){
            twain->Acquire(TWCPP_ANYCOUNT);
            ret = 1;
        }   
        FRENewObjectFromBool(ret, &result);
       return result;
    }

    FREObject setDefaultDevice(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
    {   
        FREObject result;
        uint32_t ret = 0;   
        if(isValid){
            twain->SelectSource();
            ret = 1;
        }
        FRENewObjectFromBool(ret, &result);
        return result;
    }

    FREObject initTwain(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
    {       
        FREObject result;
        uint32_t isTwain = 0;   
        if(!isValid){
            twain = new CTwain(g_hwnd, ctx);
            isValid = twain->IsValidDriver();
        }       
        if(isValid)
            isTwain = 1;
        FRENewObjectFromBool(isTwain, &result);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another Twain wraper -  C++ version of [EzTwain](http://www.eztwain.com/eztwain1.htm) - works perfect
[header file](http://read.pudn.com/downloads81/sourcecode/graph/texture_mapping/312714/ice/win32/Eztwain.h__.htm), [source file](http://read.pudn.com/downloads81/sourcecode/graph/texture_mapping/312714/ice/win32/Eztwain.h__.htm)
message loop called within same thread

```
void EZTAPI TWAIN_ModalEventLoop(void)  
{  
    MSG msg;  

    while ((nState >= 5) && !hDib && GetMessage((LPMSG)&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {  
        if (!TWAIN_MessageHook ((LPMSG)&msg)) {  
            TranslateMessage ((LPMSG)&msg);  
            DispatchMessage ((LPMSG)&msg);  
        }  
    } // while  
} // TWAIN_ModalEventLoop
```

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You don;t appear to have any thread synchronization.

First off, it looks like there is a race condition between the initialization of g_hwnd and its use in AcquireTwain etc.  This probably isn't your problem but you should take that into account - if you access g_hwnd from the main AIR thread then you must synchronize access to it using a CRITICAL_SECTION or a mutex.

However, if you can maybe just use a critical section to ensure that g_hwnd is correctly initialized and then post messages to its message queue to asynchronously do the acquire.
i.e. post a windows message to g_hwnd and then call CTwain::Acquire from within the thread.
You'd probably also need to create the CTwain from within the thread etc.  Basically, just make it thread-safe.

I've never written a native extension for Windows (only for iOS) so unsure on this... but perhaps there is a way of getting a window handle from the AIR runtime that can be used without the need for a secondary thread (unless CTwain blocks?).  This would make it a lot easier.

Comment: At firsf was trying to create CTwain with GetForegroundWindow() parameter and without mainDll file. Straight forward functions like selectSource was working fine, but because message loop was not implemented, everything else was not working. If there any way to add message loop to HWND received with GetForegroundWindow() function?